# HAProxy 2.0 LUA Fetches API - how to get request details and how to pass variable back to HAProxy

Tags: lua, haproxy

I have been scouring the internet with no luck. I have a basic LUA script for HAProxy, which looks like this:

```
core.Info("LUA script for parsing request ID element - loaded");

function parseId(txn, salt)
    local payload = txn.sf:req_body()
    -- parses hex value from element named "ID". Example payload: {"Platform":"xyz.hu","RecipientId":"xyz.hu","Channel":"xyz","CallbackURL":"http://x.x.x.x:123","ID":"5f99453d000000000a0c5164233e0002"}

    local value = string.sub(string.match(payload, "\"ID\":\"[0-9a-f]+\""), 8, -2)
    core.Info("ID : " .. value)
    return value
end

-- register HAProxy "fetch"
core.register_fetches("parseId", parseId)
```

What it does is what it says: takes a 32 characater long ID from an incoming request. In the HAProxy config file, the result is used for sticky-session handling:

```
stick-table type string len 32 size 30k expire 30m
stick on "lua.parseId" table gw_back
```

This produces two lines of log for each request:

1. ID: xyz which is logged from the LUA script
2. The detailed request data which is logged from the HAProxy config file using "log-format", e.g.:

```
Jan 20 22:13:52 localhost haproxy[12991]: Client IP:port = [x.x.x.x:123], Start Time = [20/Jan/2022:22:13:52.069], Frontend Name = [gw_front], Backend Name = [gw_back], Backend Server = [gw1], Time to receive full request = [0 ms], Response time = [449 ms], Status Code = [200], Bytes Read = [308], Request = ["POST /Gateway/init HTTP/1.1"], ID = [""], Request Body = [{"Platform":"xyz.hu","RecipientId":"xyz.hu","Channel":"xyz","CallbackURL":"http://x.x.x.x:123","ID":"61e9d03e000000000a0c5164233e0002"}]
```

I wanted to extend logging due to some strange issues happening sometimes, so I wanted to one (or both) of below approaches:

1. Pass the "ID" value back from the LUA script into the HAProxy config as a variable, and log it along with the request details. I can log the full request body, but don't want to due to GDPR and whatnot.
2. Get some request details in the LUA script itself, and log it along with the ID.

So, basically, to be able to connect the ID with the request details. If multiple requests are coming to same URL very quickly, it is difficult to find which of them belongs to a specific ID. However I couldn't accomplish these.

For the first one, I added this line into the LUA before returning the "value" variable:

```
txn:set_var("req_id", value)
```

I was hoping this would create a variable in HAProxy called "req_id", and I can log it with "log-format", but all I got was empty string:

```
ID = [""]
```

For the second one, I'm at a complete loss. I'm not able to find ANY documentation on these. I have been scouring the internet with no luck. E.g. the `txn.sf:req_body()` function which I know is working, I simply cannot find it documented anywhere, so I'm not sure what other functions are available to get some request details.

Any ideas for either or both of my approaches? I'm attaching my full HAProxy config here at the end, just in case:

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 len 10000 local2 debug
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon
   lua-load /opt/LUA/parseId.lua

   stats socket /etc/haproxy/haproxysock level admin

defaults
   log global
   option httplog
   option dontlognull
   mode http

   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000

# Request body is temporarily logged in test environment
   log-format "Client IP:port = [%ci:%cp], Start Time = [%tr], Frontend Name = [%ft], Backend Name = [%b], Backend Server = [%s], Time to receive full request = [%TR ms], Response time = [%Tr ms], Status Code = [%ST], Bytes Read = [%B], Request = [%{+Q}r], ID = [%{+Q}[var(txn.req_id)]], Request Body = [%[capture.req.hdr(0)]]"

frontend gw_front
   bind *:8776

   option http-buffer-request
   declare capture request len 40000
   http-request capture req.body id 0

   http-request track-sc0 src table gw_back
   use_backend gw_back

backend gw_back
   balance roundrobin

   stick-table type string len 32 size 30k expire 30m
   stick on "lua.parseId" table gw_back

# Use HTTP check mode with /ping interface instead of TCP-only check
   option httpchk POST /Gateway/ping

   server gw1 x.x.x.x:8080 check inter 10s
   server gw2 y.y.y.y:8080 check inter 10s

listen stats
    bind *:8774 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cer
    mode http
    maxconn 5
    stats enable
    stats refresh 10s
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /stats
    stats auth user:password
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the post
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/5-ways-to-extend-haproxy-with-lua/ from the HAProxy docs.

Reading back the variable in the HAProxy config looks like this in the "ipchecker" example:

```
    http-request deny if { var(req.blocked) -m bool }
```